# Using Image to Perform an Action instead of Button in iPhone Applciation

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can i use image to Perform an Action instead of Using Button or adding an image to Button, just wanna click button and perform particular set of instructions.
(Thanks in Advance)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [UIGestureRecogniser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer).

```
// IF your image view is called myImage
UIImageView *myImage = ...;

// Add a tap gesture recogniser
UITapGestureRecogniser *g = [[UITapGestureRecogniser alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagePressed:)];
[myImage addGestureRecogniser:g];
[g release];
```

When your image is tapped, this method will get called

```
- (void)imagePressed:(UIGestureRecogniser *)recogniser {
    NSLog(@"%@", recogniser);
}
```

---

Why don't you want to use a UIButton - it inherits from UIControl and has a lot of code that you probably don't even know exists? And it can just contain an image so it would look exactly the same?

Comment: I m trying to add a transparent image to icon but after adding, the remaining part of the Button is displayed which looks quite bad in the application, so instead of adding that image to button i just want to provide an event to that image instead of adding it to button, is there is any other way in which i can do the above task???

Comment: Set the type of your button to be Custom either in code using `buttonWithStyle:UIButtonTypeCustom` or in interface builder by selecting it from the right hand menu. That should only show the image :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the pro about using `UIButton`s is that it got all touch events built right in. You can use `UIImageView`s, but you'll need to subclass them, while in most situations, a `UIButton` using a background-image would just fit.

Comment: I agree he should be using a UIButton but you can (in 3.2 and above) add gesture recognisers to any UIView - removes the need for subclassing :)

Comment: I forgot about that, you're right! However, those gestures aren't as sophisticated as `UIControlEvents` (like `touchesUpInside`). Actually, I almost never use `UIButton`s or `UIImageView`. Most of the time, I use `UITableViewCell`s or subclassed `UIView`s to reduce memory usage.